# How do I get only the last sequence of text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used this code

```
reviews = soup.find("li", class_= "bc-list-item ratingsLabel").text.strip()
```

and got the following:

```
"4,4 out of 5 stars

                        4,4

                    (3.484 Bewertungen)"
```

The first two lines are `<span>`. How can I only get what is written within the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If `reviews` holds the string you have in the question you can do:

```py
s = reviews.split("(")[-1].split()[0]
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
3.484
```

---

Or to have it as integer:

```py
s = int(reviews.split("(")[-1].split()[0].replace(".", ""))
print(s)
```